# Python: how to check if a string contains an element from a list and bring out that element?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, if-statement

I have a list of sentences (exg) and a list of fruit names (fruit_list). I have a code to check whether sentences contain elements from the fruit_list, as following:

```
exg = ["I love apple.", "there are lots of health benefits of apple.", 
       "apple is especially hight in Vitamin C,", "alos provide Vitamin A as a powerful antioxidant!"]


fruit_list = ["pear", "banana", "mongo", "blueberry", "kiwi", "apple", "orange"]

for j in range(0, len(exg)):
    sentence = exg[j]
    if any(word in sentence for word in fruit_list):
        print(sentence)
```

Output is below: only sentences contain words with "apple"

```
I love apple.
there are lots of health benefits of apple.
apple is especially hight in Vitamin C,
```

But I'd love to print out which word was an element of the fruit_list and was found in sentences. In this example, I'd love to have an output of the word "apple", instead of sentences contains the word apple.

Hope this makes sense. Please send help and thank you so so much!

Comment: Well you know what you want - what did you try to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `any` with a generator expression, you can use a `for` clause with `break`:

```
for j in range(0, len(exg)):
    sentence = exg[j]
    for word in fruit_list:
        if word in sentence:
            print(f'{word}: {sentence}')
            break
```

Result:

```
apple: I love apple.
apple: there are lots of health benefits of apple.
apple: apple is especially hight in Vitamin C,
```

More idiomatic is to iterate the list rather than a range for indexing:

```
for sentence in exg:
    for word in fruit_list:
        if word in sentence:
            print(f'{word}: {sentence}')
            break
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `in` to check for `word in fruit_list`, then you can use `fruit` as a variable later.

In order to isolate which word was found you'll need to use a different method than `any()`. `any()` only it only cares if it can find a `word` in `fruit_list`. it does not care which `word` or where in the list it was found.

```
exg = ["I love apple.", "there are lots of health benefits of apple.", 
   "apple is especially hight in Vitamin C,", "alos provide Vitamin A as a powerful antioxidant!"]


fruit_list = ["pear", "banana", "mongo", "blueberry", "kiwi", "apple", "orange"]

# You can remove the 0 from range, because it starts at 0 by default
# You can also loop through sentence directly
for sentence in exg:
    for word in fruit_list:
        if(word in sentence):
            print("Found word:", word, "  in:", sentence)
```

Result:

```
Found word: apple  in: I love apple.
Found word: apple  in: there are lots of health benefits of apple.
Found word: apple  in: apple is especially hight in Vitamin C,
```

Answer (score -2):

This will do the job.

```
for j in range(0, len(fruit_list)):
fruit = fruit_list[j]
if any(fruit in sentence for sentence in exg):
    print(fruit)
```